# Evaluation Task to find good development company

Tags: programmer, project-management, fixed-price, proposal, interview

I hire an Indian company to develop a website for classified ads but it takes so long time and not finish yet. Therefore I decide to find a new company to do this work but I don't want to face the same situation again.

This my post: https://www.upwork.com/jobs/~0186afa2defb7fc055

I think about request **evaluation task** to find truly good company. can anyone suggest a small and effective task that my help me to find what I looking for?

Also, how can I improve my listing to attract professional development company?

any advice I will appreciate.

Thanks

***Update***

the task is paid

Comment: Possibly related: http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/6104/test-project-asking-for-too-much-to-get-a-job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asking someone to complete unpaid work as a freelancer in the hopes of landing a job isn't going to go down very well.

If it's for web design, it would be better to ask for samples of previous work (at least 5) and details on how long it took for each one and the challenges that they faced. You can very quickly see whether they are legitimate or not from this.

Comment: the task is paid.